# too much string concating at the same time make frontend blocked for a long time,how to optimize?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, websocket

I use a websocket to listenning the messages from server and show it on front end. but sometimes there are too much message come at a short period time.which made the web browser blocked for a long time. here is my code :

this is the websocket event for receiving message.

```
        $scope.logSocket.on('connect',function(){
        console.log("Log socket connected and ready to get log.");
        $scope.logSocket.on('log',function(data){
            checkStartPhase(data, app);
            appendLogText(data);
        });
```

tht code below refresh the data to frontend(using angular js):

```
    var appendLogText = function(log) {
    var t = $('#startConsoleContent');
    log += '\r\n';
    t.append('' + log);
    t.scrollTop(t[0].scrollHeight - t.height());
}
```

and I have to check the status of the log using the function checkAppPhase()

```
    var checkStartPhase = function(data, app) {
    var regExp1 = 'Downloaded app package';
    var regExp2 = 'Uploading droplet';
    var regExp3 = 'Staging failed';
    var regExp4 = 'BUILD FAILURE';
    var regExp5 = 'Starting app instance';
    if(  data.indexOf(regExp1) > -1) {
        $scope.app_step =2;
    } else if(data.indexOf(regExp2) > -1 || data.indexOf(regExp5) > -1) {
            $scope.app_step =3;
    } else if(data.indexOf(regExp3) > -1 || data.indexOf(regExp4) > -1) {
        $scope.stage_failed = true;
        $scope.app_step =2;
    }

}
```

Any advice to optimize it would be very good!

Comment: I see two things off hand. 1) you can get your reference to `$('#startConsoleContent');` ahead of time instead of every time the function gets called, and 2) using `==` instead of .indexOf is probably faster to some degree but I have no way to prove that.

Comment: The first advice is helpful, I will try it. For the second one, I used .indexOf to find if the `regExp` is a substring of the `data` string, `==` may not work.

Comment: It just looks to me like those strings are known ahead of time so it seems there's no reason for indexOf but if the strings come in randomly prepended or something then I see why you would use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is removing old entries:

```
var appendLogText = function(log) {    
    var t = $('#startConsoleContent');
    while(t.children().length>=10)
        t.find(':first').remove();
    t.append('<div>'+log+'</div>');
    t.scrollTop(t[0].scrollHeight - t.height());
}
```

This version of the method would allow only 10 entries on the log.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cu6hcjkk/

Now modify it to the number of entries you want.

Comment: I tried it and the problem is resolved, thanks a lot :)